# plots and relative table on the same page

Tags: tables, floats

I have 4 plots and 4 tables: the tables define tha values used in the plots.

I wish to have a layout of this kind:

```
table A
plot A

\newpage

table B
plot B
```

and so on.

All plots are .jpg figures.

Is it possible?

Currently I am using the option `[p]`, but I have two pages with all the plots and two pages with the table.

Comment: use `\clearpage` not `\newpage` (and if that doesn't work ask with an example document that demonstrates the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\clearpage` not `\newpage`. The difference being that `\clearpage` forces a page break but also flushes all pending floats, stopping them float past the force page break.